# How can I apply a CSS class with my script only at certain screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using bootstrap 4 and my markup is running through a `for loop` which produces eight `item` divs.

I want have five items in one row so I'm running `col-2`. But obviously that'll show six in one row.

Since I cannot add the offset in the markup (because it's in a for loop), I've added it via JS

```js
$('.item:nth-child(5n+1)').addClass('offset-1');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="test">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="item col-2">
        <p>test 1</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item col-2">
        <p>test 2</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item col-2">
        <p>test 3</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item col-2">
        <p>test 4</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item col-2">
        <p>test 5</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item col-2">
        <p>test 6</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item col-2">
        <p>test 7</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item col-2">
        <p>test 8</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I only want that `JS` to run at `min-width: 1440px`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried the same solution with css and media queries?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but you'll also need to run your script with the window size changes (by user interaction or device orientation change). It would help if you'd show the entire function.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't even need javscript for this, use CSS.
Simply add another class:

```
@media(min-width: 1440px){
  .col-5{
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't override the default Bootstrap classes, though. Better to create a custom class and avoid unexpected side effects or maintenance issues.

Answer (score 0):

try this, buddy

```
if (window.innerWidth >= 1440) {
    console.log(window.innerWidth)
    ...
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: @GalAbra _ Maybe downvoted for the console.log inclusion_ which isn't required to answer the question